# WebMethod never called

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

Having web method

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
 public static string SetCriteriaUsedFlag(bool flag)
    {
        //some action
        return "done";
    }
```

and script

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '<%= ResolveUrl("DataSetPagesActions.aspx/SetCriteriaUsedFlag")%>',
                    data: {flag: someboolvar}
                    });
```

which on client becomes to

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/MyProject/Pages/DataSetPagesActions.aspx/SetCriteriaUsedFlag',
                    data: {flag: someboolvar}
                    });
```

but **web method never calls**. Tried to change data in script like `data: "sometext"` and modified web method, but no lucks — breakpoint didn't hit, server returns html page.

In web.config:

```
<httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        </httpModules>
```

ASP.NET WebForms, .NET 2.0.

Comment: If the ajax call never triggers, maybe you have a broken `.click()` or `if` around, or something. "It never happens" is a bit light to be sure about what's going on.

Comment: @Arman Hayots which version of ASP.NET/Visual Studio are you using ?

Comment: data: {'flag': someboolvar}

Comment: u need to contenttype:application/json inside ajax request